# Getting kotlin dependency issue in buildSrc when used with Firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, gradle-kotlin-dsl, buildsrc

I am using kotlin 1.7.20 as below

```
classpath ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20")
```

When I acess below firebase code from a normal build.gradle, it gets compiled. But when used from inside of buildSrc, I get error as kotlin 1.5.1 module was expected, but found 1.7.1

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // firebase
    implementation (platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.2"))
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx")
}
```

Error is like below

`/Users/xx/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.7.10/0d0a9e3f3673ba/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.`

My main requirement is to trigger firebase in case of gradle sync through custom task.

I tried changing the values, but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This happened due to the version mismatch issue. I recommend you to update the kotlin version to the latest. For this case I am providing the required version by your system which needs changes to this line from `build.gradle`
From

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.1'
```

to

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.1'
```

Comment: As mentioned above, I am already using kotlin 1.7.20. I have done a full project search - nowhere its mentioned as 1.5.1

Comment: @virat so which version is declared in  `ext.kotlin_version ` ? and is there a classpath like this `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"` ?

Comment: Yes, Please check my first code line - it's a class path with 1..7.20 version of kotlin

Comment: @virat can you edit the question and provide the entire `build.gradle` file ?